# changing span text in li using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-lists

I have html something like...

```
<ul id="sidemenu" class="wraplist wrapper-menu">
 <li class="auto" ng-class='{"active": active == 1 }' ng-click="makeActive(1)">
    <span class="arrow material-icons">arrow_down</span>
 <li>
 <li class="auto" ng-class='{"active": active == 2 }' ng-click="makeActive(2)">
    <span class="arrow material-icons">arrow_down</span>
 <li>
<ul>
```

on ng-click=makeActive(), I want to change the value  'arrow_down' to 'arrow_right' of that particular < li> element only. and if again the same is clicked I want to change it to 'arrow_down'. Rest all < li> will have span text unchanged. How can I do this using angularjs? i.e. by using angular.element? OR is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyboardArrow refers to only one variable. So you have to create two scope variables: `keyboardArrow1` and `keyboardArrow2`

```
<ul id="sidemenu" class="wraplist wrapper-menu">
     <li class="auto" ng-class='{"active": active == 1 }' ng-click="makeActive(1)">
        <span class="arrow material-icons">{{ keyboardArrow1 }}</span>
     <li>
     <li class="auto" ng-class='{"active": active == 2 }' ng-click="makeActive(2)">
        <span class="arrow material-icons">{{ keyboardArrow2 }}</span>
     <li>
<ul>
```

### Update

According to your needs, here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SNDSxHJvBKpnTKFIODOd?p=preview).

Comment: I have changed my original question to understand it better. Can you now help?

Comment: @ghetal I updated my answer, please see if it is what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer from our discussion in comments.

**1)** In your controller, define `keyboardArrow1` and `keyboardArrow2`:

```
$scope.keyboardArrow1 = 'A';
$scope.keyboardArrow1 = 'B';
```

---

**2)** You can now display theses values like this:

```
<ul> 
  <li ng-class="{'active': active == keyboardArrow1}" ng-click="makeActive(keyboardArrow1)">
    {{keyboardArrow1}}
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{'active': active == keyboardArrow2}" ng-click="makeActive(keyboardArrow2)">
    {{keyboardArrow2}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that I also changed the `ng-class` condition.

---

**3)** When clicking a `<li>`, call `makeActive()`:

```
$scope.makeActive = function(arrow) {
    $scope.active = arrow;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it without ng-repeat?

Comment: @ghetal Updated my answer.

Comment: actually the value of expression keyboardArrow just toggles between two values for all <li>. So,  when that particular <li> is clicked, I want to set value 'A' or 'B'... ... if 'A' then set 'B' and viceversa

Comment: @ghetal Updated (again) my answer. I think it now fits your needs.

Comment: I have modified the original question... plz see